# How can I add here the Unique Key in footer setup?

Tags: reactjs

This is my footer.tsx.

I am not able to set a unique key in below component.

How can I make it easy this footer in a different way?

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  InputGroup,
  FormControl,
  Button,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import "./footer.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

type footerLinks = {
  [x: string]: string[];
};

const footerLinks = {
  footer1: [
    "Browse Experts",
    "Emergency",
    "Services",
    "Name My Price",
    "Recurring Services",
    "Service Packages",
    "Gurantees & Terms of use",
  ],
  footer2: [
    "Log in",
    "Join Our Network",
    "Resource Center",
    "Contractor Leads",
    "Terms & Conditions",
  ],
  footer3: [
    "Contact Us/Customer Care",
    "How it works",
    "FAQs",
    "Screening Process",
    "About the company",
  ],
  footer4: [
    "Handyman",
    "Cleaning",
    "Removalists",
    "Gardening",
    "Automotive",
    "All Sesrvices",
  ],
};

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="dark-bg pt-7">
      <Container className="pb-5">
        <Row>
          {/* Footer 1 Start */}
          <Col lg={2} sm={6}>
            <h6 className="footer-title">Service Seekers</h6>
            <ul className="footer-links">
              {footerLinks.footer1.map((link) => (
                <li>
                  <Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/",
                    }}
                  >
                    {link}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>
          {/* Footer 1 End */}

          {/* Footer 2 Start */}
          <Col lg={2} sm={6}>
            <h6 className="footer-title">For Service Expert</h6>
            <ul className="footer-links">
              {footerLinks.footer2.map((link) => (
                <li>
                  <Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/",
                    }}
                  >
                    {link}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>
          {/* Footer 2 End */}

          {/* Footer 3 Start */}
          <Col lg={2} sm={6}>
            <h6 className="footer-title">About Expertibly</h6>
            <ul className="footer-links">
              {footerLinks.footer3.map((link) => (
                <li>
                  <Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/",
                    }}
                  >
                    {link}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>
          {/* Footer 3 End */}

          {/* Footer 4 Start */}
          <Col lg={2} sm={6}>
            <h6 className="footer-title">Popular Services</h6>
            <ul className="footer-links">
              {footerLinks.footer4.map((link) => (
                <li>
                  <Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/",
                    }}
                  >
                    {link}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>
          {/* Footer 4 End */}

          {/* Footer 5 Start */}
          <Col lg={4}>
            <h6 className="footer-title">Join Our Newsletter</h6>
            <div className="pt-3">
              <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                <FormControl
                  placeholder="Your Email Address"
                  aria-label="Your Email Address"
                  aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
                  className="rounded-0 border-0"
                />
                <InputGroup.Append>
                  <Button className="rounded-0 border border-primary">
                    Join Expertibly
                  </Button>
                </InputGroup.Append>
              </InputGroup>
            </div>
          </Col>
          {/* Footer 5 End */}
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <div className="py-3 text-white text-center footer-caption">
        @2020 EXPERTIBLY. All Right Reserved
      </div>
      <div className="footer-chat-icon"></div>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
{footerLinks.footer2.map((link) => (
            <li key={link}>
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The map method accepts an optional parameter index, which is the index of the current element being processed in the array. And you can pass it in your map method like this.

```
 {footerLinks.footer1.map((link, index) => (
     <li>
       <Link
         to={{
           pathname: "/",
             }}
           key={index}
         >
        {link}
      </Link>
      </li>
   ))}
```